# wrong installation of KDE connect

Tags: kde

I tried to install KDE connect with no success.
However everytime I start ubuntu software center I get the following message:

"new software cannot be installed because there is a problem with the software actually installed.Do you want to repair it now ? 
The I select " repair" and a new warning: requires instalation of non trustable software - with 2 options : accept and repair - if I click accept I get always the first message: new software cannot .... etc.. etc...
So i'm stuck at this point as I cannot install anything.
I tried all sugested commands in this forum to remove the KDE package but I get the reply that kde connect is not installed sugesting that I should run the commande "apt-get -f install". But if I do that I will come to the same error as before.
How can I reoair my ubuntu software center ??

Comment: Are you using the KDE interface? Or you are using Ubuntu and you installed KDE connect?

Comment: Try uninstalling it completely using synaptic package manager

Comment: What Ubuntu release/version are you running exactly? Did you somehow managed to recover the other one from 2 days ago or did you installed it properly this time?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and I'm not using KDE interface.I tried to install KDE connect but for reason it failed.Now I can't install anything.I get always same messages everytime I start the ubuntu software center;"new software cannot be installed because there is a problem with some software installed.Then I click repair  and a new message pops up saying that that action requieres instalation of untrustable packages.I click accept and I get the first message again.I see no solution.Answering to celtic warrior I have installed ubuntu again.

Comment: OK guys.I had the intention to upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 and I decided that this is the right moment.thank you.

Comment: If you waited I would have given you a way to run KDE connect on your 14.04
And if I do, would you mark my answer as the right answer? @HilarioFerreira